# How I can add, Import and Require in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, webpack, aws-sdk-nodejs

I have a big project. Initially Backend and Frontend both wrapped in webpack bable, Both frontend and Backend are sharing the same node modules. I have segregate the backend, I don't want to use and webpack bable.

In my NodeJs code, we have used - Import and Require both. I can't not change the all the places require, or Import. There are lots of places I need to change, will be time taken.

My Package.json -

```
  {
  "name": "pr-se-bd",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "engines": {
    "node": "12.18.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "NODE_ENV=development jest test.js --testEnvironment=node --watchAll --detectOpenHandles --forceExit",
    "start": "nodemon node.js"
  },
  "type": "module",
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "aws-serverless-express": "^3.4.0",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "bluebird": "^3.7.2",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "compression": "^1.7.4",
    "crypto": "^1.0.1",
    "esm": "^3.2.25",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "firebase-admin": "^9.6.0",
    "fs": "0.0.1-security",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0",
    "node-forge": "^0.10.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.7",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "sequelize": "^6.6.2",
    "ts-node": "^9.1.1"
  }
}
```

When I ran the application - I am getting the Error -

```
The ESM module loader is experimental.
internal/modules/run_main.js:54
    internalBinding('errors').triggerUncaughtException(
```

Is there any other way we can use, import and require both in NodeJS without webpack ?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `"type": "module"` to package.json file in the backend nodejs code

Comment: "type": "module", Does not help - If you see I already added in my package.json

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to add `"type": "module"` in package.json and add the following lines when you need to `require` packages:

```
import { createRequire } from "module";
const require = createRequire(import.meta.url);
```